# Differences in the new syntax of C# 6.0 / New null check syntax?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-6.0

*First of all, I apologize for title used in this question, since I don't even know how to ask it nor how to search for it, so it may be there, somewhere, a question similar to this one.*

---

I recently stumped upon a *Potential Fix* on Visual Studio 2015 that I've never seen before. When building `EventHandlers`, I usually do something like this:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

internal void onMyEvent(EventArgs eventArgs) {
    if(MyEvent != null) {
        MyEvent(this, eventArgs);
    }
}
```

But now, Visual Studio 2015 grays out the `if` statement and corresponding brackets and, when hovered, show a message saying *Delegate invocation can be simplified*. The simplified version would look something like this:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

internal void onMyEvent(EventArgs eventArgs) {
    MyEvent?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
}
```

How does this exactly work? Wouldn't an `Exception` be thrown due to be invoking a method out of `null` or the code *stops* executing if the expression before '**?**' is null?

Also, could I replace every `if` statement that checks if a variable / method / method is `null` with the '**?**', putting aside the readability of the code?

---

***Side note:*** I'm assuming this is from the new version of the C#, 6.0, because I've never seen it before. Please, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: It is new syntax: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

Comment: And it is called Null Conditional Operator

Comment: It's way more simple that I expected it would be. Thanks @allan for your help. I'll post now an answer for this question.

Comment: FWIW your old way of invoking events isn't the best - there's a chance the final subscriber may unsubscribe between your check for null and invoking the event handler, resulting in a NRE.  You should copy it first before checking it for null, [see the first example here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @JamesThorpe since I've never ran into problems using that code, I never thought about that, but thanks for the info, although I probably won't need it from now on.

Comment: @auhmaan Yeah the new syntax allows for much cleaner event invokers now you don't need to manually make the copy yourself

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it was alreay pointed out this C#6 feature is called [Null-conditional Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).

It's also worths looking into the generated C# code with ILSpy:

```
internal void onMyEvent(EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    EventHandler expr_07 = this.MyEvent;
    if (expr_07 != null)
    {
        expr_07(this, eventArgs);
    }
}
```

As you see this is a pure compiler feature.. it just rewrites your code to the traditional null-check.

To answer you question (although I guess you already figured this out by looking at the code):

> Wouldn't an Exception be thrown due to be invoking a method out of
>   null or the code stops executing if the expression before '?' is null?

There won't be an exception thrown when your eventhandler is null. The code just won't be executed when an object before the ? is null.

Now until this point this was only a method call. Obviously if you want to assign a value which is a result of an expression with a Null-conditional Operator it is a little bit more complicated: If it is a reference type then your variable remains null, but if it would be a value type then it will be automatically nullable and will be also null if the the object on which you use the '?' operator is null.

Here is a de-compiled code for this case:

```
Program.Customer[] array = new Program.Customer[10];
    if (array == null)
    {
        int? arg_33_0 = null;
    }
    else
    {
        Program.Customer expr_1A = array[0];
        if (expr_1A == null)
        {
            int? arg_33_0 = null;
        }
        else
        {
            new int?(expr_1A.IntField);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How come you can't do `MyEvent?(this, eventArgs);`? `That?.WouldBeNice();` (if `That` were not `null` in the feature set, it would invoke `WouldBeNice()` in my developer experience :)

Comment: @toddmo Interesting point! I guess that would interfere with the conditional operator. Before a ‘?’ without a ‘.’ after it the compiler expects a bool which it then evaluates for the conditional operator. Look at this code:

bool b = Decide(); int intVal= b?(1) : 2;  (there you see the pattern from your snippet: ‘variable?(‘     )

I’m not a language expert, someone from the C# team could answer this, but I think this is the reason that you need '?.' in that case.

Comment: `MyEvent.?(this, eventArgs);` - If missing the method name, use default method name.?.?.? lol idk either, but it's not confusing to me to see that. Only Eric knows :)

Answer (score 2):

## Making it simple...

The **?** in `MyEvent?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);` it's called [**Null Conditional Operator**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) and it's used to simplify the code.

They're used to test for null before calling a method or accessing the index of a enumerable, such an `Array` or `List`.

This example is found on the page about the Null Condition Operator and it's self explanatory:

```
// null if customers is null
int? length = customers?.Length;

// null if customers is null
Customer first = customers?[0];

// null if customers, the first customer, or Orders is null
int? count = customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count();
```